# Overwrite data being sent to table if it exists already?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a script that sends data from a userform to a table on a network drive. I also have code to populate that table data back in the form for users to make edits. Say i have an existing entry, pull the data to make updates, how would make sure it overwrites an already existing entry instead of appending extra rows? Could I implement an if statement to check if it exists already?

EDITED CODE:

```
Private Sub cmdSendData_Click()

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\\OFFER_LOG_DATA_TABLE.xlsx")
    Dim wsTgt As Worksheet: Set wsTgt = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim recRow As Range

    'See if there's a match on an existing row
    '  adjust function to suit...
    Set recRow = MatchRow(wsTgt.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
                          txtCandidateName.Text, _
                          txtCurrentPosition.Text)

    'If there's no existing row to update then add a new row at the bottom
    If recRow Is Nothing Then Set recRow = wsTgt.Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    With recRow.EntireRow
        .Cells(1).Value = txtTodays_Date.Text 'section 1
        .Cells(2).Value = Me.cmbReason_for_Offer.Value
        .Cells(33).Value = txtMgrJustification.Text
    End With
        
    
    wb.Close savechanges:=True
    Application.Quit   '????
    wb.Saved = True
        
End Sub

'Return a row from a table based on matches in two columns
'   returns nothing if no match
Function MatchRow(tableRange As Range, lStore, lName) As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    lStore = Me.txtStore.Text
    lName = Me.txtCandidateName.Text
    For Each rw In tableRange.Rows
        'adjust the column numbers/match types as needed
        If rw.Cells(4).Value = lStore Then
            If rw.Cells(16).Value = lName Then
                Set MatchRow = rw
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, you can check if it already exists, using `Application.Match`, or `Range.Find`, or some other similar approach.

Comment: would I need to get rid of the `addnew` lines?

Comment: `addnew` is either the next empty row (for a new record) or the matching row if the record is not new.  You should definitely change the name to something like `recordRow` though.

Comment: @TimWilliams but what about the offset part? I guess Im confused on how I go about it after i do the range.find part. Will I have to implement another 35 lines of code with no `offset` part?

Comment: A row is a row - you would fill it the same way you already do - you could restructure your code to use a with block though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should look something like this:

```
Private Sub cmdSendData_Click()

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\TABLE.xlsx")
    Dim wsTgt As Worksheet: Set wsTgt = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim recRow As Range 

    'See if there's a match on an existing row
    '  adjust function to suit...
    Set recRow = MatchRow(wsTgt.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
                          txtCandidateName.Text, _
                          txtCurrentPosition.Text)

    'If there's no existing row to update then add a new row at the bottom 
    If recRow is nothing then set recRow = wsTgt.Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    With recRow.EntireRow          
        .cells(1).Value = txtTodays_Date.Text 'section 1
        .cells(2).Value = Me.cmbReason_for_Offer.Value
        '....
        .cells(33).Value = txtMgrJustification.Text
    End With
        
    
    wb.Close savechanges:=True
    Application.Quit   '????
    wb.Saved = True
        
End Sub

'Return a row from a table based on matches in two columns
'   returns nothing if no match
Function MatchRow(tableRange As Range, match1, match2) As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    For Each rw In tableRange.Rows
        'adjust the column numbers/match types as needed
        If rw.Cells(1).Value = match1 Then
            If rw.Cells(3).Value = match2 Then
                Set MatchRow = rw
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
End Function
```

Whatever code you have to load the existing record should keep track of which row it came from, or you will need some method to re-find the row when you save the record later.

Comment: I guess what Im confused about is when i `set recRow = ...offset(1,0)` ? Won't that always just be jumping to the next blank row for a new entry instead of replacing it if it already exists?

Comment: You need a way to match an existing row (or already know where that row is) - if there is no matching row then that's the only time you need to use `.End(xlUp).Offset()`

Comment: is it going to be hard finding a match function, which references two separate text box values and find them in two separate columns within the table? The match functions I see tend to only locate one field value

Comment: It's not a big deal to just use a loop over the records and check each row for the two matching values

Comment: is there a reason why I need to make a separate function for recordRow? Why couldn't i just do something like `matchingrow = application.match(lStore&lName,colD&colQ)` and then `set recordRow = wstgt.cells(matchingrow.row)` or something like that?

Comment: That multi-column match doesn't work in VBA.  You could maybe use Evaluate.  Basically you make it a separate function because that's a good practice to get into.

Comment: I'm trying to research match functions online, but the only resources are different use-case. do you have any links or maybe a shell that I can get started with? Sorry just very new to functions and parameters in vba

Comment: See my edits above - untested but should get you there.

Comment: So i just tested it and edited it to fit the two variables (store and name), but it skips over during the function and says the values aren't found. did i edit it incorrectly?

Comment: I don't have your data, so there's no way for me to trouble-shoot...

Comment: I am positive it's the parameters in the function doing that, it doesn't know what to search through. do I need to explicitly define the ranges and the values after the paramter? For example, tablerange = wstgt.columns("D:Q")

do I need to define that somewhere in the function? I updated my post to your code suggestion with my own little edits, what else should i do?

Comment: You either pass the match criteria to the function, or assign the values in the function, but not both.

Comment: so was I not supposed to edit your example up above? you have `match1` and `match2`, but how will the function know what those variables are in the above sub?

Comment: is what you provided supposed to just work? this is getting a bit confusing, im sorry

Comment: The function receives a range and two match values when you call it - you can use them inside the function, just as I did. The only things you would need to adjust are (1) which match values to pass to the function (2) which columns the function tries to match those against (3) how you perform the match (case-sensitive or -insensitive for example?) If you're going to be working with any programming language you need to get comfortable using methods and passing parameters.

Comment: tim, I finally understand how the parameters are functioning in the code. I changed them and the `match` variables in the function are assigning the correct values. still, it is looping through the `wsTgt` and not finding the values in columns 4 and 17, but they do exist. so I'm curious as to why Its not locating and matching them if the variable is correct via hovering